# How to obtain barium hydroxide

Tags: home-experiment

I am trying to perform the demonstration of a strongly endothermic reaction reacting barium hydroxide with ammonium nitrate.  I have been scouring the web for ways to get barium hydroxide, but none have showed any promise.  The only way I have seen to obtain it is by heating the nitrate to decomposition and reacting the oxide with water.  I would rather avoid this as I have no way to deal with the nitrogen dioxide gas that would result.

Comment: Google **buy barium hydroxide**.  You'll find several sellers on various science sites and eBay.  There are at least 5 different vendors I found immediately.  You can also buy barium oxide and dissolve it in water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy barium hydroxide. See the listing from [Flinn Scientific](http://www.flinnsci.com/store/Scripts/ck_prodList.asp) although Flinn is by no means the only seller. However, Flinn's safety information is written at a very accessible level.

Comment: Flinn will only sell to certified teachers and schools