# Examples of endothermic reactions occuring spontaneously at constant temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics

Typical spontaneous endothermic processes I can think of (e.g. melting of ice, isothermal gas expansion) involve either an initial temperature difference between the system and the surroundings, or some pressure variation.

I am looking for examples of endothermic processes, if possible molecular, that happen spontaneously at constant temperature and constant pressure, so that the process is **both endothermic and exergonic** (i.e. $\Delta G <0$).

Comment: Are you happy to count dissolving Common Salt in water? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_change_of_solution

Comment: Searching here for “endothermic dissolution” turns up more examples.

Comment: A practical example is a chemical cold pack. You break the inner bag to allow the chemicals to mix, resulting in an endothermic reaction.

Comment: The classic demo example is [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38123/79678). The chemical cold packs suggested by @theorist are excellent choices: I have one of the sodium acetate supersaturated solution ones and they may still sell the ammonium nitrate dissolution cold packs.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest reaction which is endothermic and exeronic is the reaction $$\ce{NaHCO3 + HCl -> NaCl + H2O + CO2}$$

If you add progressively some $\ce{NaHCO3}$ powder in a beaker containing $\pu{150 mL}$ $1$ or $2$ molar $\ce{HCl}$ solution initially at maybe $\pu{20°C}$, you will observe that a huge amount of $\ce{CO2}$  is produced. But the temperature goes down to $15°$, then $10°$ C, if the solution is continuously stirred by a thermometer. Important : stir ! By adding some more powder, the temperature may go down to $\pu{0°C}$ if the beaker is well isolated from the ground.

Comment: What happens if one doesn't stir?

Comment: The evolution of CO2 means that the volume of the system increases and thus that energy is transferred to the surrounding as work. Does it mean that for any process that is both endothermic and exergonique at constant p and T, the internal energy necessarily decreases? (With your example I realize that this was actually the underlying question that was bothering me when I posted the original question...)

Comment: If you don't stir, the powder does not touch the liquid. It is pushed by the bubbles of  $\ce{CO2}$ and stays hanging above the liquid, at least for a while

Comment: @TheQuark  No. Suppose (in arbitrary units) delta_H = -3, and the pV-work = +2.  Then delta_U will be -1 (also negative, just less negative than delta_H).  OTOH, if the pV-work is +4, then delta_U will be +1.  I.e., whether the direction of heat flow reverses from positive to negative when you change from constant-p to constant-V is determined by the magnitude of the pV-work relative to the magnitude of delta_H.  At atmospheric pressure, typically the pV-work will be too small to change the sign of q (direction of heat flow).  But at sufficiently high pressures, you could see a reversal.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments @IanBush has mentioned dissolving of salts.

Some salts in particular have a very endothermic dissolution process. IIRC two such salts are $\ce{NH4Cl}$ and $\ce{NaNO2}$. If you can get your hands on any one of them, then just dissolve them in a little bit of water in a test tube and you will be able to see condensation of moisture on the outside surface within a short time.

Oh, and it's not just salts, dissolution of many organic compounds is also endothermic, for example glucose dissolving in water.

(There are exceptions to this: dissolution of NaOH in water is exothermic)